# What is the use of State key in react-router Link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I just passed an object in state as below, but the data is not passed in state.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <h2> Home Page </h2>
            <Link to='/link2' state={{testing: this.state.JSONData}}  target='_blank'>
                About
            </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and accessed the state passed in a link as below,

```
import React from 'react';

export default class About extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.location.state.testing);
    return (
      <div>
            <h2> LinPage </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It returned null.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here.  **Where** you console log will inherently change the meaning of `this`.

Comment: Hi @gravityplanx, i have update question with sample code.